# how to install the virtual-box on Linux Mint 17?

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox

I need to install the virtual-box on my Linux Mint 17 machine. Also tell me if any prerequisites to install in the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

linux mint is an ubuntu derivative, you should have no problem following these instructions

[Vbox installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Installation)

Comment: Usually link-only answers get deleted but I think in this case it's OK.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I've just started participating and answering rather than only lurking

Answer (score 2):

I just installed virtualbox on Linux Mint 17. Just go to 'software sources' (which you can find on the menu), open it, and type in 'virtualbox'. Then, when it comes up, just double-click on it and hit 'install'. 

Your second question: how to run virtual machines.
You can find most of those answer online. But in short, you can install any os you want from a cd (or dvd), an iso, or a pre-built virtual machine. 

The above is what I did, and it worked without any problems. I am currently running freeBSD and one other Linux distro with it, and I have had no problems. Enjoy!

Comment: In Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon, the relevant menu item is "Software Manager" under the top-level "Administration" item.